# Loop through range, if name value doesn't appear on another sheet then copy data into third sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Good morning all

I think i'm missing an obvious step with this one but i cant see it!
I need to loop through a range, check each value within that range in sheet 8 and see if it appears in a Sheet1, if not then copy data across from the first sheet to Sheet2.
Here's what i've got so far. It will copy across the first instance it encounters but doesn't do the rest. Any suggestions where I've gone wrong / omitted

```
Sub Induction_Report()
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    
    
    Dim r As Range
    Dim S As Range
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    
    
      For i = 46 To 145
        Set S = Sheet1.Range("A1:A20000").Find(What:=Sheet8.Cells(i, 42).Value, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
        If S Is Nothing Then 'name is not found
          Sheet8.Cells(i, 42).Copy 'COPY NAME
           Sheet2.Range("C20000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats 'PASTE NAME
          Sheet8.Cells(i, 40).Copy 'COPY ROLE
           Sheet2.Range("B20000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats 'PASTE ROLE
          Sheet8.Cells(i, 43).Copy 'COPY NUMBER
            Sheet2.Range("D20000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats 'PASTE Number
          Sheet8.Cells(i, 44).Copy 'COPY SUPPLIER
            Sheet2.Range("E20000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormulasAndNumberFormats 'PASTE Supplier
          Sheet2.Range("A20000").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Value = "WEJob1"
        End If
    
         
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
      End Sub
```

Comment: I do not understand what "doesn't do the rest" means... If you want doing what your code shows, for the case of **no any much**, this is the code. No more occurrences of a NOT FOUND value may exist. Please, better describe (**in words**) what you need/try accomplishing.

Comment: Your code **does not loop trough the data values in sheet1**. It loops between 46 to 145 rows **of sheet8**. Your code does not check anything in `Sheet2`. Neither in words you do not say anything about "see if the value is shown in sheet2"... So, do you want copying in `Sheet2` **only if it is not already there**? Or, what? What do you mean by "first instance"? Please, try understanding I am saying and make a better description of what exactly you try accomplishing.

Comment: I'm sorry
I want the code to loop through the data in sheet 8, check the value against data in sheet1, and if it doesn't appear on sheet1, then paste the data into sheet 2 which will function as a report. sheet2 will be cleared of data each time this code is run so there's no issue with the value already being there.

Comment: and by first instance I mean it will work for the first value in sheet8's range but not the rest

Comment: This can only mean that all values (from row 46 to 145) can be found in `Sheet1`... Try placing a break point on the line `Set S = Sheet1.Range("A1:A20000").Find(...` and then run the code line by line, using `F8` and see what's happening. Is the next `S` `Nothing`? You can see that moving the cursor over the variable... Are you sure that want iterating starting with Sheet8 row 46 of column 46 ("AS")? What value does it show when moving the cursor over it?

Comment: Apologies for my answer (I deleted it), I somehow had missed .End(xlUp) which @FaneDuru pointed out to me. I'm as confused as to why it wouldn't work then, apart from the values already existing.

Comment: @Notus_Panda No need to apologies... Everybody can make mistakes (in understanding or doing). Anyhow, it would be faster to calculate the last empty row once, then using it for all cases, but this was not the reason of the problem, which I tried emphasizing. Important is to dare, even if you missed anything. His question looks strange to me. I am afraid that he missed something there. Maybe the column in which the code iterates,  maybe something else. If I would see the data and his code run line by line I think I will immediately understand what's happening. That's why I suggested to do it...

Comment: Are you sure you mean to be looking for the Supplier (Sheet8's column 44)? In your code you state `name is not found` , not `supplier is not found`.

Comment: I've amended the code based on your observation Notus_Panda. You are right I was mixing up looking for the supplier(44) when I should have been looking for the name (42)

Comment: And the A-column consists of the names? Have you gone through the code step by step (with the F8 key) to see what goes on?